# vue select doesn't show initial value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to show the initial value of a array of objects like this:

```
tableStyes[
{Id: 1, style: "blabla1},
{Id: 2, style: "blabla2"}
]
```

basicly i am using a computer method to give me the array from vuex store

```
tableStyles () {
  return this.$store.getters.getTableStyles
},
```

i am doing the select this way:

```
 <select class="form-control" v-model="table.tableStyle">
    <option v-for="(item,key) in tableStyles" :value="item.Id">
      {{ item.style }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

i want to get the value based on the id, i mean i want to get the text associated to the id, and the id is table.tableStyle, that is 1 at the begin that should be the selected item, but somehow it doesn't work :/.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need no computed method to display data from vuex store.

`v-model="table.tableStyle"` sets the first displayed item, if it is initialized with anything that is not included in the array, no item will be selected before you select one manually.

Try:

```
data:{ 
  return {
   ...
   table.tableStyle: this.$store.getters.getTableStyles[0] 
  }
}
```

I dont know if `this` works in data section.

Comment: doesn't work, i also don't want to initialize it with the first item, but with the item that has the id 1

Comment: Then use https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter to filter for the id 1 instead of using index zero `[0]`